# How can I substract 5% the highest and the lowest values from my data frame?

Tags: r

I would like to substract the lowest and the highest values from my data frame

```
dr <- filter(dr,
                 dr$Cena_za_metr >= quantile(dr$Cena_za_metr, 0.05),
                 dr$Cena_za_metr <= quantile(dr$Cena_za_metr, 0.95))
```

But I get error

```
Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Comment: The tidyverse uses non-standard evaluation for args, try removing the dr$ from dr$Cena_za_metr but keep it inside the `quantile` method

Comment: Now I get error                                                                                                         "Error in match.arg(method) : object 'Cena_za_metr' not found"

Comment: Post your data and you'll have this solved very quickly

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdg6yzpsvaAhXGbrwKHYQYC9UQFgg5MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AOvVaw00xttYhbqoB7L7CXC05R8r

Comment: See this example: `library(dplyr); mtcars %>% filter(dplyr::between(disp, quantile(disp, 0.05), quantile(disp, 0.95)))`